# Why doesn't given processes behave asynchronously?

Tags: unix, process, fork

I'm running the following code inside `main`, in my `.c` file.

```
int main(void){
    int id = fork();
    int n;

    if(id == 0){
      // child process
      n = 1;
    }else{
      n = 6;
    }

    for(size_t i=n; i<n+5; i++){
        printf("%ld ", i);
    }
    printf("/n");

    return 0;
}
```

As far as my understanding of `fork()` system call goes,child and parent process should run in "parallel", meaning that `printf` should print child and parent processes' values unordered. When i compile and run it, it always runs with this order:

```
6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5
```

Meaning that, parent process runs first and then child process. I've run it over 20 times and output is always the same. Do i miss something about `fork`?

I'm on x86-64 Linux machine

Comment: If you add `fflush(stdout);` after `printf("%ld ", i);`, do you see the output being interleaved? Is the output slightly different every time you run it after making the change?

Comment: should `fflush` immediately print out given value instead of buffering(i guess `printf` buffers by default)? While using `fflush`, 1  in 10(roughly) execution changes the order, but most of the time `fflush` doesn't make difference.

Comment: Yes, when `printf` sees that its output is a terminal window, it will treat the output as *line buffered*, and won't output anything until it's told to output a newline (`\n`) character. `fflush` will output whatever is currently in its buffer. So you might see some interleaving, depending on what else is running on your system. Hopefully someone can explain the order based on what a typical Linux scheduler does.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Learned about 'fflush'.